# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)

Tags: typescript

Please tell me why it doesn't work?
For example, I simplified the task. I need to understand why in this situation typescript swears.

```
type A = { a: number, b: string, c: true, d: number[], e: null, f: { a: number, b: string } };
type B = { a: number, g: string };

const A: A = { a: 1, b: "2", c: true, d: [1, 2, 3], e: null, f: { a: 1, b: "" } };
const B: B = { a: 2, g: "123" };

let result = A as (A & B);

(Object.keys(B) as Array<keyof B>).forEach(
    key => result[key] = B[key]
);

//result error
//Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
//Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigMwGdhiBLLAc3IGNNacJyATTXQkgG0AuuQh8cAG0nkAZphQZs%20ImQrVaDRlAC%20ugNwAoUJCgAhBMjQSBaxhvpMDhwywD2WGrExxEizACMpACQlFAARABM4SFsUBxcULxQgkFQkeQAzKJQ4srScgrWUGlh4eG6zu6ewOaYFn7FGVD2EQGRmRU6RoaSELXEEFRStYhwqFRQABRwAGTmAJQ9UwDyBABWECzAAHQA1hAgVFNmC2iTMMTEqCAAPAcgbrLmAHwLO7JuxACiqCwAFlNDMEHggXlBBsNJMBBA9hJYzLDDsJDEsXAB6dEQoYjDFY1BQTCRQyYiiEiLRElYljkhJUpLk1LkZrZenQCTSenPBRKUqYco6enafntTpAA)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Merge both objects?

Comment: I am writing a deep merge of objects without using "any". And stumbled on a completely simple task.

Comment: `const result: A & B = { ...A, ...B}`.

Comment: I know that this can be solved, but it is important for me to understand why exactly typescript swears. Because the task will get harder for a deep merge

Comment: It doesn't work because of [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The fix is to write a generic callback with `B[K]` on both sides of the assignment, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLyJKW).  I could write up an answer explaining if that meets your needs; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: The intersection `A & B` works here because there aren't type conflicts at the values with the same keys, but in other cases that type would be inaccurate and also cause more `never` problems (e.g. where `oA.a` is `string` and `oB.a` is `number`). A better way is to create a type with keys and values of `B` and only the keys and values from `A` which aren't overwritten by `B` during the merge, like this: https://tsplay.dev/w1palW

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigMwGdhiBLLAc3IGNNacJyATTXQkgG0AuuQh8cAG0nkAZphQZs+ImQrVaDRlAC+ugNwAoUJCgAhBMjQSBaxhvpMDhwywD2WGrExxEizACM5JRQAEQATKGs7MScPJiCQVDh5ADMolDiytJyCtZQSSGhobrO7p7A5pgWfvkpUPZhAeGpJTpGrh5exBBUUpWIZh0AFADyBABWECzAAHQA1hAgVMNmAJRoVLDExKggADyLIG6y5lAAZFA0jowAfGuzsm7EAKKoLAAWw0cIt8iGAEgen1JMBBEdhJYzOClsJDDo1h1ylQ3JIILNJG5GMNgf1EUA

Comment: Even if you assign yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is confusing because you and I know that the `forEach` loop ensures we are referring to the same key in both sides of the `=`. Here's why Typescript doesn't know:

**Problem 1:** Object.keys returns an array of string, which can't be used to index `A` nor `B`.
**Problem 2:** Since `B` has multiple types (string or number), Typescript can't guarantee the type of `B[keyof B]`, so you can `never` assign to it.

```
// Example, where without Typescript complaining you would have a bug
const a = "a" as keyof B
const g = "g" as keyof B
result[a] = B[g] // Error: Can't assign `string | number` to `never`
```

**Solution:** Cast to a single key of B

```
Object.keys(B) as Array<"a">
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigMwGdhiBLLAc3IGNNacJyATTXQkgG0AuuQh8cAG0nkAZphQZs+ImQrVaDRlAC+ugNwAoUJCgAhBMjQSBaxhvpMDhwywD2WGrExxEizACMpACQlFAARABM4SFsUBxcULxQgkFQkeQAzKJQ4srScgrWUGlh4eG6zu6ewOaYFn7FGVD2EQGRmRU6RoaSELXEEFRStYhwqFRQABRwAGTmAJQ9UwDyBABWECzAAHQA1hAgVFNmC2iTMMTEqCAAPOGo4QB8CzuybsQAoqgsABZThmCBxACCeUEGw0kwEEwOEljMMMOwkMSxcAHo0eChiN0ZjUFBMJFDBiKASItFiZiWGSEpSkmTUuRmtk6dAJNI6bIyUglKVMOUdHTtPz2p0gA)